# NSProgressIndicator Displaying Incorrectly (Indeterminate) - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsprogressindicator

In my project I am using an NSProgressIndicator to show that an NSTask is running, and it is set so that it does not display when stopped. It shows when it isn't stopped and disappears when it is stopped, however when it appears it looks like this:

[image: Incorrectly shown]

Instead, it should look like this but doesn't:

[image]

As you can see, it has no border. How can I make it have one? Is this a known bug?

Comment: Are you instantiating this with a XIB? If so, what is your Focus Ring set at in the XIB?

Comment: It is set at default right now, but in a couple of hours when the NSTask finishes again (VERY long script and I am still trying to get it right) I will try "exterior" and "none"

Comment: Default should be fine.  Are you doing any drawing in the background in that window?

Comment: Neither exterior, none, or default work. I don't have anything drawing in the background either.

Comment: OK, it works now. I fixed it by unchecking "only show when active" and manually hide and unhide it when I need to.

Comment: I found the same thing, doing the manual hide and show resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bug, because as you mentioned in the comment, setting the NSProgressIndicator to hide and show manually resolves the problem for me too.

*Putting this here because this should be resolved as an answer, at the very least it's the only work around.*